# Want the entire row of the mat-table to be evenly filled with the same color

Tags: css, angular-material

[Please look at the attachedment of my question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HensF.png)

Comment: please create a small demo over stackblitz

Comment: It will be unable to show a working demo because it has lots of other dependencies....Shall i share the css code here?

Answer (score 1):

```
table.mat-table tr:nth-child(even) {
    background: #f3f3f3;
}
```

This works for me, Check  https://stackblitz.com/angular/lnojalejppj